# How to restrict input box to only accept postive numbers and have a maxium value of 10

Tags: javascript

Im trying to only use javascript to accept positive numbers in the input field

I've tried  to use this, but don't know how to set a max  value of 10.

```
if (Number.isInteger(num) && num >= 0) {
    
}
```

Comment: The same way as your test for the minimum, just the other way round o.O

Comment: And why not `<input type="number" min="0" max="10" step="1" />`?

Comment: ^ right, wouldn’t you just add `&& num <= 10`, or is that not what you’re asking for?

Comment: This is one of those questions that is so simple, we aren't sure if we're understanding the OP correctly.  You already have a condition "greater than or equal to zero".  Do you really not know how to add "and less than 10" to that expression?

Comment: i would assume you're trying to make the number range dynamic.  In any case the best method is to limit the user from entering invalid values in the first place (see andreas comment above) and if you need to manually adjust them then you can change the min and max through javascript using setAttribute.

Comment: my brain is just fried atm been coding all day if (Number.isInteger(num) && num >= 0) && <10){ would that be the solution
    
}

Comment: you have an extra parentheses and it would be <= 10 i assume.

Comment: this may be beyond what you're doing, but if your input boxes are bound to a model, you can set the attribute in the model [Range(0, 10)] and that's all you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
if (Number.isInteger(num) && num >= 0 && num <= 10) {
    
}
```

You can also do the min/max attribute thing mentioned in the comments, although do be warned that that has different implementations per browser and isn't supported on IE 9 and below.

Comment: just a question, i   can change the "num"  value to any other variable correct?

Comment: Yes, it can be any variable you want.

Comment: thansk you for your help,  just one more. i want to include multiple variables to be calculated the exact same how  would I go about this? `if (Number.isInteger(num) && num >= 0 && num <= 10  ||  Number.isInteger(num2) && num >= 0 && num <= 10  && Number.isInteger(num) && num >= 0 && num <= 10 ) {
    
} `

Comment: If you want both of them to be valid (num AND num2) do this: `Number.isInteger(num) && num >= 0 && num <= 10 && Number.isInteger(num2) && num2 >= 0 && num2 <= 10`. If you want one or the other or both to be valid, do this: `(Number.isInteger(num) && num >= 0 && num <= 10) || (Number.isInteger(num2) && num2 >= 0 && num2 <= 10)`

Comment: ie9 and below are no longer considered supported by microsoft and they have specifically requested people not use them way back in 2019.  https://mashable.com/article/microsoft-stop-using-internet-explorer-browser

Comment: True. Doesn't change the fact that some enterprise applications still have to support it, though :/

Answer (score -1):

the best solution is to set it initially and then adjust the range on them.
This will allow you to dynamically change them from javascript as needed.  This function should suit your needs and is reusable.

```
<input id = "myControlID" type="number" max="10" min="1" >
<script>
    setNumberRange(0, 100, "myControlID"); //usage

    function setNumberRange(minValue, maxValue, selector) {
        var input = document.getElementById(selector);
        input.setAttribute("min", minValue);
        input.setAttribute("max", maxValue);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just try this on the input tag

```html
<input type="number" max="10" min="1" >
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Did you read the question?  You aren't checking the max.

Comment: Why are `charCode`'s getting involved here?

Comment: looks like he was trying to filter to numbers, incorrectly.